# Cannot update Editable grid in Azure portal extension

Tags: javascript, azure, typescript, azureportal

I'm developing an Azure **portal extension that includes an editable grid blade**.
The grid's blade is opened from a selector and therefore **contains a parameter provider**.

The grid is **initialized with the edit scope of the parameter provider**, which is an observable array, and **enabled for row editing and inserting new rows**.

When I try to update the grid, **changes to existing rows are not shown and creating new line yields an empty line**, like below:

[image: Empty line when adding new row]

I don't see any errors in the console while debugging.

Here's how I initialized the grid:

```
private _initialize(container: MsPortalFx.ViewModels.PartContainerContract): void {
    var extensions: number = MsPortalFx.ViewModels.Controls.Lists.Grid.Extensions.EditableRow | MsPortalFx.ViewModels.Controls.Lists.Grid.Extensions.ContextMenuShortcut,
        extensionsOptions: MsPortalFx.ViewModels.Controls.Lists.Grid.ExtensionsOptions<DataModels.IItem, DataModels.ISelectionItem>,
        viewModel: MsPortalFx.ViewModels.Controls.Lists.Grid.ViewModel<DataModels.IItem, DataModels.ISelectionItem>;

    // Set up the editable extension options.
    extensionsOptions = this._createExtensionsOptions();

    // Create the grid view model.
    viewModel = new MsPortalFx.ViewModels.Controls.Lists.Grid.ViewModel<DataModels.IItem, DataModels.ISelectionItem>(
        container,
        null,
        extensions,
        extensionsOptions);
    viewModel.showHeader = true;
    viewModel.columns(this._columns);
    viewModel.rowAdd = () => {
        // code that extension authors need to execute when a row is added should go here.
    };
    this.editableGrid = viewModel;
}

private _createExtensionsOptions(): MsPortalFx.ViewModels.Controls.Lists.Grid.ExtensionsOptions<DataModels.IItem, DataModels.ISelectionItem> {
    return <MsPortalFx.ViewModels.Controls.Lists.Grid.ExtensionsOptions<DataModels.IItem, DataModels.ISelectionItem>>{
        editableRow: {
            // Supplies editable items to the grid.
            editScope: this.parameterProvider.editScope,
            // put the new row at the top.
            placement: MsPortalFx.ViewModels.Controls.Lists.Grid.EditableRowPlacement.Bottom,
            // Create no more than 5 new rows.
            maxBufferedRows: 5,
            // Allow the modification of existing items.
            allowEditExistingItems: true,
            // Allow the creation of new items.
            allowEditCreatedItems: true,
            // Track the valid status
            valid: ko.observable<boolean>()
        }
    };
}
```

I've reviewed several sample blades of editable grid but couldn't identify what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set the **editScopeMetadataType** property of the parameter provider, which required for determining the edit scope's entity type:

```
this.parameterProvider = new MsPortalFx.ViewModels.ParameterProvider<DataModels.IItem[], KnockoutObservableArray<DataModels.SchemaItem>>(container, {

    // This was missing.
    editScopeMetadataType: wrapperTypeMetadataName,

    mapIncomingDataForEditScope: (incoming) => {
        return ko.observableArray(incoming);
    },

    mapOutgoingDataForCollector: (outgoing) => {
        return outgoing();
    }
});
```